# how to send temperature DS9097 sensor data to apache and keep an archive of it

Tags: apache-http-server, temperature, sensors

I want to show at my website this temperature readings data.

USB DS18B20 with the prolific adaptor PL2303. 
instructions for Debian are:

```
apt-get install digitemp
digitemp_DS9097 -i -s /dev/ttyUSB0
digitemp_DS9097 -q -t 0 -c .digitemprc
```

and if possible to keep an hourly archive of readings

Answer (score 0):

I would probably use [this version of digitemp](http://illx.org/digitemp/index.jsp), which integrates with MySQL. then just write a web app in php or whatever scripting langague you choose, to query hourly readings and display them.